# Duplicate rows that belong to multiple groups before group by

Tags: sql, database, group-by, pivot

Let's say I have a table of customers and I want to group them depending on their first and last name and then get the mean age of each group.

However, my rules are not mutually exclusive. For example :

- First name begins with letter "A"
- Last name begins with letter "A"

And some customers:

```
id   first_name    last_name    age  
1    Ava           Adams        36
2    Alexander     Williams     44
```

The first customer matches both rules and the second one only matches the first rule.

The expected result for the mean age of each group should be:

- 40 for Group 1 (Ava and Alexander)
- 36 for Group 2 (Ava)

But more than that, I would really like to group the customers like below (calculating a group field that can be used for aggregation) :

```
Ava            …        Group 1
Ava            …        Group 2 
Alexander      …        Group 2
```

How could I do that using one SQL query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using conditional aggregation:

```
select
    avg(case when first_name like 'A%' then age end) avg_age_first_name_A
    avg(case when last_name  like 'A%' then age end) avg_age_last_name_A
from mytable
where first_name like 'A%' or last_name like 'A%'
```

---

*Edit*: on the other hand if you are just looking to generate two groups, one option is `union all`:

```
select t.*, 'group 1' grp from mytable t where first_name like 'A%'
union all select t.*, 'group 2' from mytable t where last_name like 'A%'
```

Comment: Thanks ! I've edited the question. In fact, I really want to get the different groups in order to aggregate using group by. It's like I have to duplicate rows that belong to multiple groups.

Comment: @GhizlaneAdarrab: that sounds quite different from your original question... I edited my answer accordingly.